# Override Taxonomy Template

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I'm trying to list all the products tied to a specific taxonomy. For some reason the template won't work when trying to access "http://www.myexample.com/product_categories/funiture/", I tried `taxonomy.php`, `taxonomy-term.php` and nothing. Here's my code: http://pastie.org/7934453

```
add_action('init', 'register_cpt_product');

function register_cpt_product() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Products', 'product'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'product'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New Product', 'product'),
        'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Product', 'product'),
        'edit_item' => _x('Edit Product', 'product'),
        'new_item' => _x('New Product', 'product'),
        'view_item' => _x('View Product', 'product'),
        'search_items' => _x('Search Products', 'product'),
        'not_found' => _x('No products found', 'product'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No products found in Trash', 'product'),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent Product:', 'product'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Shop', 'shop'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions', 'page-attributes'),
        'taxonomies' => array('Product Categories'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type('product', $args);
}

add_action('init', 'register_taxonomy_product_categories');

function register_taxonomy_product_categories() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Product Categories', 'product_categories'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'search_items' => _x('Search Product Categories', 'product_categories'),
        'popular_items' => _x('Popular Product Categories', 'product_categories'),
        'all_items' => _x('All Product Categories', 'product_categories'),
        'parent_item' => _x('Parent Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent Product Category:', 'product_categories'),
        'edit_item' => _x('Edit Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'update_item' => _x('Update Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'add_new_item' => _x('Add New Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'new_item_name' => _x('New Product Category', 'product_categories'),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => _x('Separate product categories with commas', 'product_categories'),
        'add_or_remove_items' => _x('Add or remove product categories', 'product_categories'),
        'choose_from_most_used' => _x('Choose from the most used product categories', 'product_categories'),
        'menu_name' => _x('Product Categories', 'product_categories'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_tagcloud' => false,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'query_var' => true
    );

    register_taxonomy('product_categories', array('product'), $args);
}
```

Comment: In your case the template would be taxonomy-`product_categories.php`. If if's not working, go to your taxonomy page in admin, click on "view" for any custom taxonomy, check URL and in the source, the classes on the `<body>` tag, it will help you to check what kind of page WP thinks you're on.

Comment: When you view the page, what does the body class say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display):

> - `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, and    taxonomy's term were someterm WordPress would look for
>     `taxonomy-sometax-someterm.php`. In the case of Post Formats, the
>     taxonomy is 'post_format' and the terms are `post-format-{format}`.
>     i.e. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php`
> - `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` - If the taxonomy were sometax, WordPress    would look for `taxonomy-sometax.php`
> - `taxonomy.php`

You registered your taxonomy as `product_categories`, so you should be using `taxonomy-product_categories.php` to create a template for all terms in that particular taxonomy.

Use `taxonomy-product_categories-furniture.php` to target only the one term referenced in your URL.

`taxonomy.php` will be used for all taxonomies.

Comment: Taxonomy.php doesn't even work, the theme outputs index.php instead for some reason.. is this normal?

Comment: It is not normal. It sounds like something is broken. Do you have this problem with any other theme, like Twenty Twelve?

Comment: Very helpful thanks, at the end of the day I needed to reset my permalinks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Did you save the permalink after creating custom post type

Take a look at codex [Custom Post Type Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates)

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. I remember having todo this in the past but it's been awhile since I last played around with WP's tax.